# Oracle to MySQL Simple Query Coversion SELECT a + b AS total FROM (SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b FROM DUAL)

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have a simple Oracle Query

```
SELECT a + b AS total FROM (SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b FROM DUAL)
```

I will use MySQL this time so I tried doing this:

```
SELECT a + b AS total FROM (SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b)
```

But it's giving me error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: You must add subquery alias. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=56958d19e5602a19ead5037337c2e217 *But it's giving me error* The error is not related to shown code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every subquery or derived table requires an *alias* in MySQL (as well as most flavors of SQL), so use this version:

```sql
SELECT a + b AS total
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b
) t;   -- change is here
```

Note also that I removed the `FROM dual` clause in the subquery.  In MySQL, constants can be selected without using the `dual` table (unlike in Oracle, where it is necessary).

Comment: So I was just missing an alias! Silly of me. Thank you!